# How to make PHP Table Generator with an array of unknown size

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a table generator for my website which displays all records saved in a database, it works but only for the first record because I haven't declared each individual job.

I want to make it so that by running `addRow($job)` my table generator will display every record that would appear in the foreach loop. My guess is this works by changing `$job = new Job()` and `$tableGenerator->addRow($job);` to work with an array that doesn't have a declared size, however after playing around with this I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

```
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs'); 
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $job = new Job($row['title'], $row['category'], $row['salary'], $row['location'],  $row['description']);
} 
$tableGenerator = new TableGenerator();
$tableGenerator->setHeadings(['Title','Category','Salary','Location','Description']);
$tableGenerator->addRow($job);
echo $tableGenerator->getHTML();
```

Comment: Please take a look at how the foreach cycle works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with logic, you close foreach loop to early.

```
$tableGenerator = new TableGenerator();
$tableGenerator->setHeadings(['Title','Category','Salary','Location','Description']);
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs'); 

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $job = new Job($row['title'], $row['category'], $row['salary'], $row['location'],  $row['description']);
    $tableGenerator->addRow($job);
}

echo $tableGenerator->getHTML();
```

Comment: That was simple, think I've been staring at php too long today to notice the smaller mistakes-Thanks